# Accessing TCP option fields from nodejs.net

Tags: node.js, tcp

I have a node.js server application that listens to raw TCP connections using the `net` module.

In order to keep track of network latency, I want to access the `TSval` and `TSecr` TCP fields. How exactly should it be done and where? The server layout is nothing spectacular:

```
var tcps = net.createServer(function(c) {
     /* socket initialization */
     ...

     c.on('data', function(chunk) {
         /* message processing */
         ...
     }
}

tcps.listen(serverPort);
```

Comment: That kind of low-level access to TCP packets is not available in node.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [@mscdex's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2050455/mscdex) comment:

> That kind of low-level access to TCP packets is not available in node.js